# Reading the time a file was added to a folder

Tags: java, c#, windows, file, date

I am writing a piece of software that is to monitor the time a file was added into a specific directory. I would need to do this in both c# and java. However, I am not so much interested in when the files was created as this could be days before they are actually moved into the directory of interest. I have been loking around, but unable to find anything. The closest I've found so far in java is:

```
File file = new File(yourPathHere);
long lastModified = file.lastModified();
```

But that does not give me the time the file was moved into the folder. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Simple and straight not possible, modified date gets updated only when there are changes to the file, moving doesn't update the date.

Comment: You can monitor the directory in question, using the [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class in C#. In all likeliness, Java offers its own wrapper for [FindFirstChangeNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417.aspx) (and similar) API calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using windows, have a look at this rules :

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/299648

It seems that when you move a file, it does not change its modification or creation date.
It's changed only when doing a copy.

As an alternative, you can regularly scan your folder, like every 1 minutes and when you discover a new file, you put it in a log and  write it's discovery date.

As IInspectable is saying, FileSystemWatcher and FindFirstChangeNotification are probably the way to go to avoid coding a scanner